# Convert JSON categories tree to database table

Tags: json, csv, recursion, jq, flatten

Imagine I have a categories tree like this JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "text": "engine",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "text": "exhaust",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "text": "cooling",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "4",
            "text": "cooling fan",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "id": "5",
            "text": "water pump",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "text": "frame",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "7",
        "text": "wheels",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": "8",
        "text": "brakes",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "9",
            "text": "brake calipers",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "10",
        "text": "cables",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I convert it to this flat table?

```
id  parent_id   text
1   NULL        engine
2   1           exhaust
3   1           cooling
4   3           cooling fan
5   3           water pump
6   NULL        frame
7   6           wheels
8   6           brakes
9   8           brake calipers
10  6           cables
```

I found similar questions and inverted questions (from table to JSON) but I can't figure it out with jq and its @tsv filter. Also I noticed the "flatten" filter is not often referenced in the answers (while it looks to be the exact tool I need) but it might be because it was introduced recently in the latests versions of jq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution which uses jq's [recurse](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#recurse(f),recurse,recurse(f;condition),recurse_down) builtin:

```
  ["id","parent_id","text"]
, (
      .[]
    | recurse(.id as $p| .children[] | .parent=$p )
    | [.id, .parent, .text]
  )
| @tsv
```

Sample Run (assumes filter in `filter.jq` and sample data in `data.json`)

```
$ jq -Mr -f filter.jq data.json
id  parent_id   text
1       engine
2   1   exhaust
3   1   cooling
4   3   cooling fan
5   3   water pump
6       frame
7   6   wheels
8   6   brakes
9   8   brake calipers
10  6   cables
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDLbsIwEEX3fMXIYkGlJCp9F6lS/yOyKpMMxK1xXD8KUtNfr@uEmgQI481czbl3bL9/@vyb8JIsyJwkxOLOhhblmksMuqi4KDVKsojUzYDaVcwZe4zRn@SfvO3Joq4Fl@vRwLszDFZMXgq97@kts6hBuY06hdsTDQ@9YaXZZvxRj4PUClGYS@ufenCp2Qea0bjnEwoKJrhCbc4vGoPn14NvYEuBIyxtPHSVt56EKBZm9q3rOyudtNMEZhM4VJbTg2pAY@G0wVnGS2AGpqqBLG7JaQCyfejLVMHVwJcHQxKHoWnXxdw918CrNV/g/W@tLK@l8WkqnRApl8rZIDTbprWzQfwB)

Comment: Brilliant! I can now pipe directly after curl with curl ...  | jq -Mr '(.[] | recurse(.id as $p| .children[] | .parent=$p) | [.id, .parent, .text]) | @tsv'

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to define a recursive function, like so:

```
def children($parent_id):
  .id as $id
  | [$id, $parent_id, .text],
    (.children[] | children($id)) ;
```

With your data, the filter:

```
.[]
| children("NULL")
| @tsv
```

produces the tab-separated values shown below.  It is now easy to add headers, convert to fixed-width format if desired, etc.

```
1   NULL    engine
2   1   exhaust
3   1   cooling
4   3   cooling fan
5   3   water pump
6   NULL    frame
7   6   wheels
8   6   brakes
9   8   brake calipers
10  6   cables
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! At the end, I chose the applied the solution of jq170727 because it uses the recurse function built-in jq.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses a recursive function:

```
def details($parent):
   [.id, $parent, .text],                   # details for current node
   (.id as $p | .children[] | details($p))  # details for children
;

  ["id","parent_id","text"]                 # header
, (.[] | details(null))                     # details
| @tsv                                      # convert to tsv
```

Sample Run (assumes filter in `filter.jq` and sample data in `data.json`)

```
$ jq -Mr -f filter.jq data.json 
id  parent_id   text
1       engine
2   1   exhaust
3   1   cooling
4   3   cooling fan
5   3   water pump
6       frame
7   6   wheels
8   6   brakes
9   8   brake calipers
10  6   cables
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDfToMwFIfveYqTzostKYtT559543sQYjp6GNWuxbZsS5yvLrZzBDaYsdz0wHe@3zm8fdTJJxGcLMiMUOJw5/wV1Uoo9HVWCMkNKrJoqJsOtStYZd0pln7RI3nbkpnWUqjVoPCuh0HO1CXpvKW3zKGBslqX53B4mob7tiE3bD281EPHWiBKeyn@sQWXhr2jHdQ9nVGQMSlKNLY/aCOeXXd@A1tKHGDTfc0xB46OCWnHVyXz39xkEQFAMhWcwvEVhWlQpRT6Z9T0Q64NZJUJDaA0x6AZew0w60Wwh2mTn6S@amMnk57mCEbPkbckYSVKfmd5PdwPm6UDwxTIOJqI@uSTFFVJGXL@2iDaw4uzG/jXGUGm1QaNA6fBd9X1ty6d0MrWcRzSYqHKyvnCsG2sK@eLHw)